# Control ribbon buttons for each opened window separately

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin

I'm writing an Outlook add-in that has its own ribbon with buttons defined in an xml manifest. Besides the main Outlook window (explorer), separate windows can be opened (inspectors) and all of them have the same ribbon. I would like to control the properties of ribbon buttons independently. But in my `getPressed` button handlers I always get the same ribbon object. And `OnRibbonLoad` is always called only once. So, what I would like to hypothetically see is that there is as many ribbons as the number of inspectors ( + explorer) there. In terms of behavior: imagine an explorer shows an email and there is also an inspector with another email in it. Both windows have the same ribbon, but I want to be able to enable/disable buttons in every window independently.

Here is my manifest:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui" onLoad="OnRibbonLoad">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
    <tab idMso="%1">
        <group id="addin_group" label="Title" getImage="GetAddinGroupImage">
            <toggleButton id="addin-enable-toggle"
                size="large"
                getLabel="GetAddinEnabledStatusLabel"
                onAction="OnAddinToggled"
                getPressed="GetAddinEnabled"
                getImage="GetAddinEnabledImage"
                getEnabled="GetAddinTogglePermission"
                />
            <button id="ButtonSetting"
                getImage="GetSettingButtonImage"
                size="large"
                label="Configure"
                screentip="Configure"
                supertip="Opens the configuration dialog."
                onAction="OnSettingButtonClicked"
                getEnabled="GetAddinValid"
                />
            <button id="ButtonRefresh"
                getImage="GetRefreshButtonImage"
                size="large"
                label="Refresh"
                screentip="Refresh scan result"
                supertip="Remeasure the threat level of the current item."
                onAction="OnRefreshMailResults"
                getEnabled="GetAddinValid"
                />
            <button id="ButtonReport"
                getImage="GetButtonReportImage"
                size="large"
                label="Report"
                screentip="Report mail"
                supertip="Reports the opened mail."
                onAction="OnButtonReportPressed"
                getEnabled="GetEmailReportingEnabled"
                />
            <button id="ButtonUnlock"
                getImage="GetButtonUnlockImage"
                size="large"
                label="Unlock"
                screentip="Unlock mail"
                supertip="Unlocks the opened mail."
                onAction="OnButtonUnlockPressed"
                getEnabled="GetEmailUnlockingEnabled"
                />
        </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

`%1` in `<tab idMso="%1">` is replaced on either `TabReadMessage` or `TabMail` depending on `ribbonId` value that I get in IRibbonExtensibility::getCustomUI function:

```
//IRibbonExtensibility Methods
STDMETHODIMP CConnect::GetCustomUI(BSTR RibbonID, BSTR *RibbonXml)
{
    if(!RibbonXml)
    {
        return E_POINTER;
    }

    //Get the ID of the ribbon that a custom UI is being requested for
    QString ribbonIdStr = BSTR2QString(RibbonID);

    static QMap<QString, QString> ribbonViews;

    if(ribbonViews.isEmpty()) { //initialize
        ribbonViews["Microsoft.Outlook.Mail.Read"] = "TabReadMessage";
        ribbonViews["Microsoft.Outlook.Explorer"] = "TabMail";
    }

    if(ribbonViews.contains(ribbonIdStr)) {
        *RibbonXml = XmlResource2ComBSTR(ASSET_RIBBON_MANIFEST, &ribbonViews[ribbonIdStr]);
    }

    return S_OK;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a control callback is fired (onAction, getImage, getEnabled, etc.), you will receive `IRibbonControl` as a parameter. `IRibbonControl.Context` property will be either `Explorer` or `Inspector` object, from there you can get to `Inspector.CurrentItem` or `Explorer.Selection` to  perform the action on the per-item basis.

Comment: Seems to be what I was looking for. I falsely thought that callback's `ribbon` parameter is of IRibbonUI, which I already saved somewhere else during add-in initialization. Still I have one issue. When I call `IRibbonUI::Invalidate`, it only invalidates ribbon of the top-level window. Any chance to trigger invalidation of windows that are not in the focus?

Comment: Do you pass any parameters to Invalidate?

Comment: I use Invalidate that's without parameters. Just tried InvalidateControlMso with `TabReadMessage` and `TabMail` but now button callbacks `getEnabled` and others are not even called

Comment: Does it get called when you switch to that (inactive) inspector?

Comment: I don't call it explicitly on switch, but when I bring inactive inspector or explorer to top, ribbon gets invalidated automatically and my buttons are reevaluated. Just want to find a way to invalidate the ribbon of an inactive window,  if possible

Comment: I thinks that's just Outlook optimization to prevent updates that the user most likely won't see.

Comment: Appreciate your help. And thanks for such an awesome add-in! Could not be more helpful when I was dealing with Outlook object model.